# how to split string based on multiple delimiters like '==' , '!='

Tags: java

I want to split string based on multiple delimiters

I have tried `"property == Test property1 != Test1".split("[==!=]")` 
 and 
`"property == Test property1 != Test1".split("['==''!=']")`

but it is splitting based on `'='` not `'=='.`

please help me out

Comment: String[] parts = <Your String>.split("=="); Isn't this working ?

Answer (score 2):

Since [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), you can use `|` ([OR operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)):

```
String[] splitted = myString.split("==|!=");
```

Comment: downvoter, please help me improving my answer by letting me know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps I'm not understanding your question but why aren't you just doing `"property == Test".split("==")`
?
If your intention is to use regex then you can group your matches and separate them with an `|` (or) as in
"property == Test".split("(==)|(!=)")

Answer (score 0):

Write a multi-character regex alternative using | alternative operator, not a [] character specifier. Character specifiers specify how to match a single character only.

```
String[] results = input.split( "(==|!=)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    theStringYouWantToSplt.split("==|!=");
```